# Cannot import external library (.jar) to Eclipse project

Tags: java, github, jar

I am having issues adding an external jar library to my project in Eclipse. I downloaded the [javallier](https://github.com/n1analytics/javallier) library from GitHub and added it to my referenced libraries. In my package explorer, it looks like this:
[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQN0d.png)

Somehow, Eclipse can neither find the source attachment or the Javadoc location:
[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7qLi.png)

I tried downloading the java source attacher (which somehow I cannot download) and I also tried adding the source attachment manually, yet I do not know where to link it to.

Comment: Learn to use maven or gradle for dependency management.

Comment: Hint: the real answer is ... to accept that most things you can think of asking here ... have been asked before. Just download the other 2 JARs from the javallier release page, and then follow the instructions in the "duplicated" question answers.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your project -> Click properties at the bottom -> Select Java Build Path on the left -> Select libraries tab -> Click on classpath -> Click Add External Jars Button -> Select the library Jar -> Click open